# Flask-SQLAlchemy raises ImportError: cannot import name 'app_ctx' from 'flask.globals'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask app with the following `requirements.txt`:

```
flask==2.1.3
flask-sqlalchemy
```

I started getting the following error when I run the app:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'app_ctx' from 'flask.globals'
```

Why did this error start happening, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

When you declare `flask-sqlalchemy` in `requirements.txt` without a version, it will automatically be updated to latest version. `flask-sqlalchemy>=3.0` does not support `flask<2.2`.

To fix the problem you should upgrade to Flask >= 2.2 as well.

```
flask==2.2.2
flask-sqlalchemy==3.0.2
```

Applications should always include `==version` for each dependency in their `requirements.txt` file, and pin all libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Flask-SQLAlchemy 3 requires Flask >= 2.2. Update Flask.

---

Flask < 2.2 and Flask-SQLAlchemy < 3 no longer receive updates, so while you can pin to previous versions instead of upgrading, you should prefer upgrading to continue receiving support.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use flask-sqlalchemy==2.5.1
flask-sqlalchemy newest version is 3.0.0, which is pulished on 10/4/2022,if you have to use this version, code change is needed

Answer (score -2):

if your flask version is 3.0* then you should use flask-sqlalchemy version 2.5.1 this is will definitely solve the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).